# How to disconnect on a custom event python-socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, python-socketio

I have the 2 handlers:

```py
@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect', sid)

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid, environ):
    # perform some user management stuff
    # perform some cleaning as well
    print('disconnect', sid)
```

I want to trigger the `disconnect` event handler (as I want to perform some specific operations on disconnection), but on a custom event named `leaveWorkbench`.

- does `sio.disconnect()` coroutine actually calls the even handler `disconnect`?
- should I emit an event `disconnect` this way:

```py
@sio.event
async def leaveWorkbench(sid):
    await sio.emit('disconnect')
```

(seems from the docs not a good idea as "reserved"(?) + it would be caught by the client so probably not a working solution)

- or should I simply turn the event handler as a method ? with use of `sio.discconect`

```
async def disconnect_handler(sid):
    # operations to be performed on disconnection
    await sio.disconnect(sid)??

@sio.event
async def leaveWorkbench(sid):
    await disconnect_handler(sid)

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    await disconnect_handler(sid)
```

- At last, other "cleaner" alternatives?
  Important note: I make use the `session` object at disconnection

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to call `sio.disconnect(sid)`.

But note that the `disconnect()` method just initiates a disconnection that then happens in the background. The disconnect handler for the affected client will eventually be called, but it may not be immediate (i.e. may take a second or two). The client will also be notified that it is being disconnected.